# label encode multiple categorical values in a row

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

My y_train consists of **multiple ingredients**. Each consists of different ingredients separated by **comma**. It is basically a **multiclass classification problem**. My y_train looks like this

```
df['ingredients_str'].head()

0    romaine lettuce,black olives,grape tomatoes
1    plain flour,ground pepper,salt,tomatoes
2    eggs,pepper,salt,mayonaise,cooking oil
3    water,vegetable oil,wheat,salt
4    black pepper,shallots,cornflour,cayenne
Name: ingredients_str, dtype: object
```

I tried with **sklearn label encoder** to encode the categorical variables.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(df['ingredients_str'])

0    28560
1    26783
2    10595
3    38379
4     2798
Name: encoding, dtype: int64
```

How to convert that column in labelencoder?

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: Output should be like this [2, 8, 5, 6, 0]

Comment: try `le.fit_transform(df['ingredients_str']).astype(str).apply(list)`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to retrieve in each cell the list of label encoded labels. To do that you can unflatten your label column, process each column and then recompress the output dataframe to a column.

```
labels = pd.DataFrame(df.str.split(',').values.tolist()).fillna('')
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([item for sublist in labels.values for item in sublist])
labels = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([le.transform(labels[col]) for col in labels.columns]))
labels.apply(lambda x: [list(x)])

0    [[12, 11, 6, 17, 2]]
1    [[1, 8, 10, 16, 14]]
2    [[7, 13, 13, 18, 5]]
3     [[0, 15, 9, 13, 3]]
4       [[0, 0, 4, 0, 0]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I used your method but I got the same output like this
`0    [[28560, 26783, 10595, 38379, 2798, 26798, 241...`

Comment: Ok, my guess is you have string values in your cells instead of lists as I assumed. I edit my answer to add a `split`.